# Why is MobileFirst Server Configuration Tool not letting me deploy with libertyAdminUser and libertyAdminPassword?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-server

I'm trying to deploy a MobileFirst server to a local Liberty server configured with an LDAP server.

When I try and deploy my server configuration the admin task fails due to lack of attributes for connecting to Liberty.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\IBM MobileFirst Platform Server Data\Server Configuration Tool\Configuration_Hello MobileFirst Server\Hello MobileFirst Server.xml:88: The element <installWorklightAdmin>, <jmx libertyAdminUser=".." libertyAdminPassword="..."/> is missing. A default user cannot be created for this server.
```

I have tried updating the server configuration file manually before deploying, but the server configuration tool is just saving over the changes.

How can I resolve this problem from within the Server Configuration Tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Server Configuration Tool in MFP 7.0 can't be used to make an install on a Liberty server that is configured with LDAP.

In the simplified install process of the Server Configuration Tool, it automatically creates a Liberty Administrator in a basic registry and this is not possible if Liberty is configured with LDAP.

If you don't want to create ant files manually, you can:

- Export the ant files that you created with the Server Configuration Tool (Menu File/Export Configuration as Ant files...)
- Edit them so that they have the right attributes in the jmx element (you need to provide the login of password of a user that will be used as Liberty Administrator and that the apps will use to perform JMX calls)
- Run the ant files as described here 
  For the admin: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/r_wlconsole_ant_tasks.html
- For the runtime: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/c_project_war_file_ant_tasks.html

You may encrypt the password of the JMX user with the Liberty securityUtility program (in LibertyInstallDir/bin)

Comment: Would I also need to have the runtime deployed before configuring the LDAP?

Comment: I have not tested, but don't think you need. The runtime deployment is not doing anything to the basic registry. If you configure LDAP after you installed the admin you need to modify the user in <administrator-role> and the values of the corresponding jndi properties ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.user and ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.pwd